# <welcome-file-list> being ignored in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs

my web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>restapp</display-name>
    <distributable/>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My main Application class looks something like this:

```
package com.example.restapp;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {}
```

my directory structure looks like this:

- src/main/webapp

  - /fonts
  - /img
  - /WEB-INF
  - index.jsp
  - index-qa.jsp
  - stylesheet.css

My jax-rs rest app endpoint is successfully served from `http://localhost:8080/restapp/api/test`

My index.jsp is successfully served from `http://localhost:8080/restapp/index.jsp`

And yet, when a GET is performed on `http://localhost:8080/restapp/` Tomcat returns with a 404.

While I could fix this with some URL rewrites and such, I know Tomcat supports this and would just like to understand why this isn't working. I've tried any number of combinations of adding `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` tags, etc., and have given up and now I'm just looking for why this is broken and what I can do to resolve this. Java servers are not my friend today.

Answer (score 1):

According [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming), you must follow `war` file naming conventions:

[image]

Comment: Going to check on this later - if this solves my problem I'll be sure to upvote.